# xml.Marshal ignore struct if it's empty

Tags: xml, go

I need to output an XML file, and I've constructed a few structs that represent it As a basic example, say this:

```
type Parent struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"parent"`
    Name    string   `xml:"name,omitempty"`
    Age     int64    `xml:"age,omitempty"`
    Child   Child    `xml:"child,omitempty`
}

type Child struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"child,omitempty"`
    Name     string   `xml:"name,omitempty"`
    Gender   string   `xml:"gender,omitempty"`
    Thoughts string   `xml:",innerxml,omitempty"`
}
```

I expect that when I create a `Parent` without defining the child, and then marshal it into an XML file...

```
parent := Parent{
    Name: "Beatrice",
    Age: "23",
}
_ = xml.MarshalIndent(parent, "", "    ")
```

...that I should get an XML file not containing a `child` tag:

```
<parent>
    <name>Beatrice</name>
    <age>23</age>
</parent>
```

Instead, I get this:

```
<parent>
    <name>Beatrice</name>
    <age>23</age>
    <child></child>
</parent>
```

Why is the empty `<child></child>` tag there, and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few syntax errors but you can set child as a pointer:

```
type Parent struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"parent"`
    Name    string   `xml:"name,omitempty"`
    Age     int64    `xml:"age,omitempty"`
    Child   *Child    `xml:"child,omitempty"`
}
```

When it's nil, it will be empty.

[Working Demo](https://play.golang.org/p/pAEDVj7lUxw)

Comment: Also note that xmlName is `XMLName`